# Django filter and count in template tag

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-template-filters

I'm trying to filter and count a specific `QuerySet` in the template with Django template engine. Cant get it to work. The `film_list` is the context and `film` is the table and `language` is a field. Any tips on how to use filter and count at the same time in the template engine? Or should I solve it in another way?

```
{% if filmlist.film.language == "danish" %}
      {{ film_list.all.count }}
{% endif %}
```

View

```
class FilmListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    paginate_by = 150
    model = Film
    context_object_name = 'film_list'
    template_name = 'movies/movie_list.html'
```

Comment: can you provide your views, ``{{film_list.count}}`` should work

Comment: @ankitTiwari thanks for the respons ive added the view in the descriptoion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate over your context to get each object like this

```
{% for item in filmlist %}
   {% if item.language == "danish" %}
          {{ film_list.count }}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```